# Visual Studio 2013 publish website with source code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

My Visual Studio 2013 publishes website with source code. All .cs files are included in publish.

How can I publish without source code ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686946/web-application-wont-publish-without-cs-files

Comment: You could/should start by reading up, trying something and then, if something specific doesn't work, asking here. Check out [help]